# Permission errors when embedding civi-event on home page

Tags: civievent, error, permissions, registration

I've used the shortcode to embed a test event on our home page.

But when the page loads I now get:
[image]

> "Sorry but we are not able to provide this at the moment.  You do not
>   have permission to access this page. Return to home page."

If I'm logged into the site I have no problem. And if I remove the event code it also works. Can you tell me how I can set permissions for guest users of the site?

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the permissions of the CMS CiviCRM runs on (e.g. Drupal). You need to grant anonymous users the permission to "register for events" and probably also "view event info".

Maybe you could also add your CiviCRM version as well as the one of your CMS.